# Railstutorial.org Validating unique email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails, railstutorial.org

In section 6.2.4 of *Ruby on Rails 3 Tutorial*, Michael Hartl describes a caveat about checking uniqueness for email addresses:  If two identical requests come close in time, request A can pass validation, then B pass validation, then A get saved, then B get saved, and you get two records with the same value.  Each was valid at the time it was checked.

My question is **not** about the solution (put a unique constraint on the database so B's save won't work).  It's about writing a test to prove the solution works.  I tried writing my own, but whatever I came up with only turned out to mimic the regular, simple uniqueness tests.

Being completely new to rspec, my naive approach was to just write the scenario:

```
it 'should reject duplicate email addresses with caveat' do
  A = User.new( @attr ) 
  A.should be_valid          # always valid

  B = User.new( @attr )
  B.should be_valid          # always valid, as expected

  A.save.should == true      # save always works fine

  B.save.should == false     # this is the problem case
  # B.should_not be_valid    # ...same results as "save.should"
end
```

but this test passes/fails in exactly the same cases as the regular uniqueness test; the `B.save.should == false` passes when my code is written so that the regular uniqueness test passes and fails when the regular test fails.

So my question is "how can I write an rspec test that will verify I'm solving this problem?"  If the answer turns out to be "it's complicated", is there a different Rails testing framework I should look at?

Comment: This is a pretty good first question BTW.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's complicated. Race conditions are so nasty precisely because they are so difficult to reproduce. Internally, `save` goes something like this:

1. Validate.
2. Write to database.

So, to reproduce the timing problem, you'd need to arrange the two `save` calls to overlap like this (pseudo-Rails):

```
a.validate    # first half of a.save
b.validate    # first half of b.save
a.write_to_db # second half of a.save
b.write_to_db # second half of b.save
```

but you can't open up the `save` method and fiddle with its internals quite so easily.

But (and this is a big but), [you can skip the validations entirely](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#skipping-validations):

> Note that `save` also has the ability to skip validations if passed `:validate => false` as argument. This technique should be used with caution.

So if you use

```
b.save(:validate => false)
```

you should get just the "write to database" half of `b`'s `save` and send your data to the database without validation. That should trigger a constraint violation in the database and I'm pretty sure that will raise an [ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/StatementInvalid.html) exception so I think you'll need to look for an exception rather than just a false return from `save`:

```
b.save(:validate => false).should raise_exception(ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid)
```

You can tighten that up to look for the specific exception message as well. I don't have anything handy to test this test with so try it out in the Rails console and adjust your spec appropriately.

Comment: Lovely.  Thanks.  It took me several tries to check because... I had actually done the uniqueness wrong, and my indices were **not**, in fact, unique.  The actual error from the console was `ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique: SQLite3::SQLException: column email is not unique: ...`.  And, ultimately, I needed `lambda` to check the exception thing:  `lambda { B.save(:validate => false ) }.should raise_exception(ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique)`

Comment: @mcdave: Cool, tests are supposed to find bugs :)